# Vim indent in LaTeX align goes crazy

Tags: vim

I start with the following in a LaTeX document:

```
\begin{align*}
    u(x, t) &= \frac a2 \int_0^t \dif s \int_{x-a(t-s)}^{x+a(t-s)} \dif y \sin(\omega y) \\
\end{align*}
```

Then I go on and enter the second line, Vim aligns the `&`, which is sort of neat. It all goes well just before the first `}`:

```
\begin{align*}
    u(x, t) &= \frac a2 \int_0^t \dif s \int_{x-a(t-s)}^{x+a(t-s)} \dif y \sin(\omega y) \\
            &= \frac{1
\end{align*}
```

Then I enter the `}` and it does this:

```
\begin{align*}
    u(x, t) &= \frac a2 \int_0^t \dif s \int_{x-a(t-s)}^{x+a(t-s)} \dif y \sin(\omega y) \\
                  &= \frac{1}
\end{align*}
```

With every `}`, it gets indented a little more. After a while, the whole `align*` is completely unreadable.

How can I make Vim stop doing this?

[My complete .vimrc](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1310158/)

Comment: I have similar issues with html files, would be nice to know how to deal with this. You can try :set noautoindent in the meantime

Comment: I use `filetype indent`, that should do HTML correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. gvim ignored my noautoindent settings in my .vimrc. I checked the settings in a .tex file with `:verbose set ai?` and it revealed that autoindent was enabled through the vim-latex plugin. To disable indentation after braces put the following code in your .vimrc (or .vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim):

```
let g:tex_indent_brace=0
```

If you do NOT use vim-latex, try to find out which script is causing the indentation.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it. It was set to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem via `:set expandtab` (the workaround of panos did not work for me). It seems, that the vim plugin get confused, when you have tabs and spaces mixed in the file. So I set in my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd Filetype tex setlocal expandtab
```

See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces for details about tabs and spaces in vim.

Answer (score 0):

panos's and Stephan Kulla's solutions didn't work for me.  What did work was creating a file ~/.vim/indent/tex.vim containing the single line `let b:did_indent = 1` (from [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_stop_auto_indenting)).  This turns off all indentation for files of filetype `tex`, including LaTeX files.